# Swapping arrays using pointers

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, swap, function-definition

I was trying to swap two arrays using pointers.
What I wanted was to swap using a call by reference.

This code I wrote is given below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int **a, int **b) {
    int *temp = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int main() {
    int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int arr2[] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    swap((int**)&arr1, (int**)&arr2);

    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) printf("%d\t", arr1[i]);
    printf("\n");
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++) printf("%d\t", arr2[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

The output of the code is:

```
6   7   3   4   5   
1   2   8   9   10
```

instead of:

```
6   7   8   9   10  
1   2   3   4   5
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Think a little bit about that `malloc` call, and the assignment `temp = *a`... What happens with the memory that is allocated by `malloc`? If there any way to `free` it?

Comment: And `(int**)&arr1` is not correct. The fact that you need to explicitly cast the result of `&arr1` is an indication of that.

Comment: A pointer to an array is not a pointer to a pointer. You misinterpret the first 2 integers as a pointer and swap them. A pointer seems to have same size as 2 integers. That is why the first 2 values are swapped.

Comment: And anyway, you're not really swapping arrays, you attempt to swap pointer to the arrays (which will not swap the arrays themselves).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this call

```
swap((int**)&arr1, (int**)&arr2);
```

the passed pointers point to first elements of the arrays `arr1` and `arr2`.

So within the function `swap`

```
void swap(int **a, int **b) {
    int *temp = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

dereferencing the pointers like for example

```
*a
```

results in reading the first two elements of the array `arr1` as a pointer because in your system `sizeof( int * )` is equal to `2 * sizeof( int )`.

That is values of first two elements of the arrays are interpreted as values of pointers.

And the obtained output confirms that

```
6   7   3   4   5   
1   2   8   9   10
^^^^^
```

Moreover the function has a memory leak because at first memory was allocated dynamically and its address was assigned to the pointer `temp` and then the pointer was reassigned

```
    int *temp = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));
    
    temp = *a;
```

So the address of the allocated memory was lost and the memory was not freed.

You can not swap arrays such a way. You need to swap each pair of elements of the arrays.

The function can look for example the following way

```
void swap( int *a, int *b, size_t n ) 
{
    for ( int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p, ++b )
    {
        int temp = *p;
        *p = *b;
        *b = temp;
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
swap( arr1, arr2, 5 );
```

A less flexible function can look the following way

```
void swap( int ( *a )[5], int ( *b )[5] ) 
{
    for ( int *p1 = *a, *p2 = *b; p1 != *a + 5; ++p1, ++p2 )
    {
        int temp = *p1;
        *p1 = *p2;
        *p2 = temp;
    }
}
```

And the function is called like

```
swap( &arr1, &arr2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all lets fix your swap function:

```
void swap(int **pparr1, int **pparr2)
{
    int *temp = *pparr1;
    *pparr1 = *pparr2;
    *pparr2 = temp;
}
```

This function now swaps the two pointers that `parr1` and `parr2` are pointing to.

Then lest update the way to call this function:

```
int *parr1 = arr1;  // Make parr1 point to the first element of arr1
int *parr2 = arr2;  // Make parr2 point to the first element of arr2

// Swap the two pointers
swap(&parr1, &parr2);
```

And then we print using the pointers instead of the arrays:

```
printf("arr1 = [ ");
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", parr1[i]);
}
printf("]\n");

printf("arr2 = [ ");
for (unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    printf("%d ", parr2[i]);
}
printf("]\n");
```

This will print the arrays as if they were swapped, but in fact the arrays themselves are *not* swapped. You can verify by printing using the arrays `arr1` and `arr2` themselves.

If you want to swap the actual contents of the arrays, you need a loop to actually swap the elements themselves:

```
// Function to swap two integer values
void swap(int *p1, int *p2)
{
    int temp = *p1;
    *p1 = *p2;
    *p2 = temp;
}

// Function to swap two arrays
void swap_arrays(int *pa1, int *pa2, size_t size)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        // Swap each separate element of the arrays
        swap(&pa1[i], &pa2[i]);
    }
}
```

Call like

```
swap_arrays(arr1, arr2, 5);
```

After this the contents of the arrays themselves have been swapped.

Answer (score 1):

> `swap((int**)&arr1, (int**)&arr2);`

It looks like your idea is to have `swap` swap the address of `arr1` with the address of `arr2`. Variables in C, including arrays, do not work this way, and this idea cannot possibly work.

`arr1` is a name for the array. It is not the address of the array, nor is it a variable whose value is the address of the array. There is no pointer to the array that can be swapped with a pointer to the array `arr2`.

When the compiler processes `int arr1[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};`, it creates an array of five `int`, and then it uses `arr1` to refer to that array. Wherever `arr1` is used, the compiler creates code that will refer to the array. It does not do this by storing the address of the array in some memory location you can swap with another address. It has ways to access the array using registers and processor instructions set up for that.

In `swap((int**)&arr1, (int**)&arr2);`, you take the addresses of `arr1` and `arr2` and convert them to `int **`. The address of `arr1` is the address where its contents are. What is at that address in memory is the `int` elements, not a pointer. So the `int **` type does not make sense for this; the address of `arr1` is not the address of an `int *`.

The reason you get the output you do is that `int` objects are four bytes in your C implementation and `int *` objects are eight bytes. So when `temp = *a;` attempts to get the `int *` that `a` should be pointing to, it gets the first eight bytes in `arr1`. Then `*a = *b;` replaces those eight bytes with the first eight bytes in `arr2`. And `*b = temp;` replaces the first eight bytes in `arr2` with the saved eight bytes from `arr1`.

Note that, in these three statements, `temp` is used to hold eight bytes from `arr1`. The value it was given in `int *temp = (int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));` is lost when `temp` is assigned another value in `temp = *a;`.

Also note that this behavior you observed in this instance is not specified by the C standard, and different behavior can result in other circumstances, including alignment errors and surprising transformations of the program by compiler optimization.

Comment: @ryyker Arrays naturally *decay* to pointers to their first element, but arrays aren't the same as pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign whole arrays to each other in a single operation using `=`; you must either use a library function like `memcpy` or assign each element individually.

Under most circumstances, *expressions* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted, or "decay", to expressions of type "pointer to `T`" and the value will be a pointer to the first element.  If you called the function as

```
swap( arr1, arr2 );
```

it would be equivalent to writing

```
swap( &arr1[0], &arr2[0] );
```

So you're *already* passing the arrays "by reference", just not in the way you're probably thinking.

The easiest way to do what you want would be something like this:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b, size_t count )
{
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < count; i++ )
  {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = b[i];
    b[i] = tmp;
  }
}
```

Alternately, you could use `memcpy` with a temporary array:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b, size_t count )
{
  int tmp[count]; // C99 or later
  memcpy( tmp, a, count );
  memcpy( a, b, count );
  memcpy( b, tmp, count );
}
```

In this case `tmp` is a *variable-length array*, whose size is provided by a runtime value.  VLAs are useful for things like this if the array size isn't too big, but they're only available for C99 and later, and are optional after C2011.  If your arrays are very large or VLAs aren't available, then this would be a case for dynamic memory:

```
void swap( int *a, int *b, size_t count )
{
  int *tmp = calloc( count, sizeof *tmp );
  if ( tmp )
  {
    memcpy( tmp, a, count );
    memcpy( a, b, count );
    memcpy( b, tmp, count );
    free( tmp );
  }
}
```

The first method (swapping each element individually) would be my preference. It avoids any kind of dynamic memory management, it's straightforward, it's not making a bunch of library calls, etc.

In all three cases, you'd call it as

```
swap( arr1, arr2, 5 );
```

Beware explicit casts, especially pointer casts - they're usually a sign you're doing something wrong.